# Facebook scraper not reading php generated meta tags?

Tags: php, facebook, metadata

So some weird issue has been going on lately with some of our sites. We have an index.php template, which generates og meta tags based based on some parameters like language etc. This has been working for over a year now, Facebook (and other sites) parsing the metadata correctly. Which is expected, because php content is rendered on the server, right?

Yesterday I got notified by a colleague that it's not anymore. Check this url for example:

https://360.energyville.be

If I check the source, all the metadata is there, description, keywords, title, etc. And yet this one:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2F360.energyville.be%2F

doesn't seem to see any of those except for the og:url. Which is because I just added that as a string literal!

In other words, if I take any meta tag and hard-code it into the file, it works. But if the same content is generated by PHP, it doesn't. Even though the output of the PHP is the exact same thing, down to the last character.

Any ideas?

Comment: _“which generates og meta tags based based on some parameters like language etc.”_ - and where do those parameters come from? Are you trying to evaluate stuff like `Accept-Language` – which the Facebook scraper simply might not send?

Comment: That's it! But the weird thing is it used to work before, without any hiccups. Did they change it recently? 

Anyway, thanks a lot :)